# Typescript : infer type of union of specific strings

Tags: typescript

I have type of

```
type IPermissionAction = 'update' | 'delete' | 'create' | 'read'
```

and iam trying to build object with one of IPermissionAction allowed like this

```
const object =  {
                  subject: 'correspondence',
                  action: 'update' as keyof IPermissionAction
                }
```

but i getting error

```
Argument of type 'string | number | unique symbol' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IPermissionAction'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'IPermissionAction'.ts(2345)
```

tried keyof but didnt work

Comment: `'update' as keyof IPermissionAction` -> `'update' as IPermissionAction` there is no keys here to speak of.

Comment: Although with that said, it's poorly designed. You should have a  type for what `object` is instead of using type assertions to achieve the implicit typing. Also, `IPermissionAction` is quite wrong. The `I` prefix is for interfaces of objects. And even then it's arguable that it should be used in TS. But it's definitely not appropriate for a union type of literals.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this would be:

```js
type IPermissionAction = 'update' | 'delete' | 'create' | 'read';

type OtherType = {
    subject: string,
    action: IPermissionAction
}

const object: OtherType = {
    subject: 'correspondence',
    action: 'update'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use that kind of type assertion to constrain `object.action` as type `IPermissionAction` and you won't need an extra type for `object`. Just remove the `keyof` operator.

```
type IPermissionAction = "update" | "delete" | "create" | "read";

const object = {
  subject: "correspondence",
  action: "update" as IPermissionAction
};

object.action = "";
// ~~~~~~~~~~ Type '""' is not assignable to type 'IPermissionAction'.
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgChATgWwJYGd2oPYDsCCAxsDrlALxQBEArmACYCGwEVUAPtfRADYQttOVQogjNWHaqMb0qAbgBQCwnnTAo2AEYArCMQpQA3gqhR0NHXuAAuaisSj0YPN1yFWAGhNRGxUrdoGcTZGdFgEFAwsPCISPAUAX0UFLV1iADpfOLJKKnkgA)